# Blue screen of death stopcode – CRITICAL SERVICE FAILED

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, file-corruption

On June 29th, as usual I was playing a heavily modded Skyrim that freezes and crashes a lot. I decided to stop playing and started photoshop to edit some screenshots from the game, but when I opened it, it gave me an error that said:

“Photoshop has encountered a problem with the display driver, and has temporary disabled enhancements which use the graphics hardware.”

I clicked ok, and I was able to continue so I ignored the error and kept using photoshop. There was some screen tearing, but nothing else happened. After about half an hour I opened Microsoft Word 2016, and suddenly I got an error as well that said:

“Were sorry, but Word has run into an error that is preventing it from working correctly. Word will need to be closed as a result.”

I realized this is a serious problem, and restarted my computer. During boot up I got the blue screen of death, and windows tried to automatically do a startup repair but it failed multiple times. After trying out different startup options the only one that has worked so far is, disable driver enforcement.

Every time I restart or start the pc, I have to repeat the process, and some things don’t even start like device manager and windows defender.

**Things I have tried are:**

1. `sfc /scannow` found corrupted files, but it failed to repair some of them.
2. Windows restore fails too.
3. `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth` and Restorehealth didn’t do anything either.
4. I also realized my page file size was set to 400mb, when changed it to a higher number it temporary let me open device manager, but now it doesn't work anymore.

The only thing I haven’t tried is to do a complete reset from boot menu, but if this is a hardware problem, then is a reset even worth it?

[image: Screenshot of the errors]

Comment: What was the exact output of sfc?That you need to disable driver enforcement could indicate some kind of malware modifying drivers.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Here's a link: http://imgur.com/F9cO6P8

Comment: Photoshop doesn't like other apps 'stealing' its OpenGL RAM, & is very likely to take the GPU or machine down when it gets all snippy about it - but... that's always fixed by a reboot; so it feels more hardware... [pure guess]

Comment: And what's in the CBS.log file?

Comment: we need the sfc log file, not the report to go look at the log file... Trouble is, sfc saves that log forever, so you need to hone it down a bit. Try `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"` & post the result

Comment: @nullterminatedstring link to cbs log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B766PFnrUO-BdUd6SHhIZ3k0dmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: too big to search, try the extract method above, which will pull only salient info

Comment: @Tetsujin results: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B766PFnrUO-Bd3JudUlnelpUM0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try opening a command line as admin and enter `bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON`, then restart your pc, boot in safe mode, open command line and execute `sfc /scannow` again and post the new CBS.log, then boot normal and check if you still get the errors.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring ok this is kind of weird, it says that "An error has occurred setting the element data. The value is protected by secure boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted." Also I cannot currently boot in safe mode.

Comment: @Benny Actually it isn't weird, it's totally normal because you have "Secure Boot" enabled.You need to disable it by doing the follow:1. In windows press the WINDOWS key on your keyboard 2. Click on the power on/off icon 3. Hold SHIFT on your keyboard and click on "Restart" and release SHIFT 4. Click on "Troubleshoot" 5. Click on "Advanced options" 6. Click on "UEFI Firmware Settings" 7. Find a option called "Secure Boot" and disable it 8. Redo the things I told you to do in my previous comment

Comment: @Benny If the system isn't working after doing the sfc scan in safe mode, you could do a inplace upgrade to your current version (so in fact more a "inplace reinstallation").That "inplace reinstallation" would keep all of your personal files, programs, apps, settings, registry entries and everything else except system files and that should fix every possible corrupted system file.For such a "inplace reinstallation" you would need a windows installation ISO containing the exact same windows version (same edition, same build and same language pack) as you currently have and you should...

Comment: ...make a full backup of your current system because the upgrade could fail and I think you will loose the ability to downgrade to your old windows 8 without a backup.Ask me or google if you want to do such a "upgrade".

Comment: @nullterminatedstring thanks for all the info, I'm currently trying out those things one by one, I will tell you about the results soon.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring After holding shift and clicking on restart, the only option that I had was to turn off the PC, btw I created a windows iso image using macrius reflect

Comment: @Benny The missing menu could be caused by corrupted system files or simply by a missing windows 10 recovery partition.To disable "Secure Boot" you definitely need to open your UEFI/BIOS settings and without a working recovery partition you need to directly open your UEFI setting by pressing some key on boot (like F12, F11, F10 or the DELETE key) but what exact key or key combination depends on your mainboard, so you would need to google for the right combination.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring I finally was able to fix all the issues by doing the in place installation upgrade as you mentioned. It was the safest option, and saved me a lot of time doing any extra troubleshooting. Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts to fix this problem using various techniques and methods, I finally figured out a way to fix all the issues.

I fixed this by downloading the media creation tool from Microsoft's website and upgraded the windows (in-place installation) while keeping all my personal files and apps.

This is by far the safest and easiest option available, and I wish this feature was integrated into the OS. rather than having to download the utility separately. This way people can solve their issues much quicker and have a better chance of avoiding any data loss.

Comment: [Here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) is a guide which explains how to do such a in-place upgrade/installation to repair windows for people reading this.

Comment: Glad to hear that! There is a simpler trick of which I make frequent use when hitting BSOD that aren't related to the boot files: 1. If I can't even get to the recovery and run the command prompt I use a live Ubuntu pendrive/or plug the disk to another system. 2. Navigate to `%windir%\system32\config\ ` and append .OLD to the DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE and SYSTEM files. Navigate to `%windir%\system32\config\RegBack\ `, copy these same files to the config folder. Sometimes I even create a DRIVERS file backup so I can rollback it in the event of a driver related crash in future.

Comment: @Benny You might want to free some disk space by deleting useless data created while "upgrading"/"reinstalling" windows.To do that press WINDOWS+R on your keyboard, enter "cleanmgr", press ENTER, check "Temporary Windows installation files", uncheck everything unwanted and click on "OK" (You might also want to delete your old windows installation this way but you would loose the ability to downgrade to your old windows 10, which was unusable anyway.)

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Yeah, I thought about doing those things. I've always done that in the past as well when upgrading or reinstalling windows on my previous pc.

Comment: @Benny You should do a scan for malware to ensure that the file corruption wasn't caused by malware.I would use [ESET Online Scanner](https://download.eset.com/special/eos/esetonlinescanner_enu.exe) and after that [Malwarebytes](https://downloads.malwarebytes.com/file/mb3/).For Malwarebytes click on "Settings" and "Deactivate Premium Trial" to get the normal free edition and to start a full scan click on "Scan" > "Custom Scan" > "Configure Scan", check "Scan for rootkits", under "PUP" select "Ignore detections" and under "PUM" the same,

Comment: select every drive you want to scan and finally click on "Scan Now"(Don't forget to uninstall Malwarebytes after usage).Let's hope your system is clean.